# Does setting HttpOnly on cookies on the server side affect cookies created in the browser?

Tags: javascript, cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly

I'm managing a server and have been looking into setting HttpOnly for my cookies.

While I don't have any cookies which are interacted with on both the server and client side, would enabling this option for all cookies prevent client-side generated cookies from being accessed on subsequent page loads?

To clarify, this would be set as a server option.
I'm using Apache so this would be something like:
`Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure`
in the Apache config.

Additionally, the question is based on using cookies for data storage. `LocalStorage` is outside of the question's context, even if it is a superior method to storing data purely used on the client side.

Comment: What's a "front-end only cookie"? If you don't need the information on the server, don't use a cookie. Use `sessionStorage` or something like that instead.

Comment: Have you tested it and checked if it worked?

Comment: Are you sending the "client side generated" cookies back to the user when you receive them on the server? If not, then your Apache won't alter them.

Comment: Http only cookies can only be accessed by the server, it prevents Javascript access (full stop) That's their point. So if you want to manipulate the cookie using Javascript, then you can't use HTTP only. this covers the [high level concepts quite well](http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/)

Comment: @Bergi `sessionStorage` is a fantastic thing, minimum browser version requirements are not.

Comment: @Bergi Maybe this question relates more to the fundamentals of cookie storage then. If you create a cookie in the browser, nothing fancy, will it ever be passed to the server by itself? If not then the answer to the original question would always be no.

Comment: Accepted as a duplicate question on the basis that logically cookies are never passed back to the server by themselves, and will therefore never be passed through the HttpOnly setting. Makes 100% sense. Thanks @Liam

Comment: @Sean: Yes, it's a (http) cookie, and will sent to the server on every request. That's the reason why using them for data storage is despised and `localStorage` was developed (especially for larger data)

Comment: @Bergi Yes, absolutely. I'm aware there is a better alternative for storing data on the front end. This is not the question though, I'm afraid. Using `LocalStorage` is out of the question when you need to support IE7. You're saying cookie data is sent to the server on every request (which is counter to what I was lead to believe), I'm wanting to know if this is then affected by httpOnly. The question is now losing points because I've been told two different things, and noone has posted a clear answer.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: Wow, that edit changes the question substantially, near to the point where it invalidates my answer :-/

Comment: @Bergi feel free to revert it! Opening a new question is probably better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would enabling this option for all cookies prevent client-side generated cookies from being accessed on subsequent page loads?

Yes. JS cannot access the values of cookies that the server response tagged with `HttpOnly`, and it cannot write new values to them either.

I haven't found out what exactly happens when JS tries to write to one nonetheless, browsers seem to shadow the http-sent one with a locally stored one that is only accessible by the clientside script. I wouldn't rely on this behaviour though, the write might simply be ignored. In older browsers there seem to have been bugs where the http-only cookie was written to.

However, there is no way to enable `HttpOnly` for *all* cookies. You have to set it on every exchanged cookie individually, so this option will be only enabled for those cookies that the server does sent to the client with that flag.

So if you are configuring your Apache to enable that flag on all outgoing cookies, it still depends on whether your server application does mirror all the cookies sent by the client. Usually it would not, and send only the cookies it does want to set (for itself, to be used on the server).

Comment: Can you access a cookie that was created with JavaScript, then set to HttpOnly?

Comment: Not sure about that. The JS might still have access to the value that is stored locally (at client side) and was sent with the request, but it does definitely not have access to the new value that came back with the response. Anyway, you just shouldn't "set a client-created cookie to httponly" :-)

Comment: Tested on Chrome. I set a cookie in the client side, reloaded the page, and was able to access the cookie as normal (was not flagged with httpOnly). I could also access this cookie on the server (in my case, PHP's `$_COOKIE`)

However, when I set/changed the value of the cookie on the server side (`setcookie`) and reloaded the page, chrome reported two cookies with the same name: One with httpOnly (set to the new value), one without (the value set client side). The server side used the value of the value set on the server, the client used the client-side set value.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I guessed. I haven't found (or looked close enough) though whether this behaviour is standard and documented somewhere.